# If the rank of a real symmetric matrix be 1 show that the diagonal elements of the matrix cannot be all zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**If the rank of a real symmetric matrix be 1 show that the diagonal elements of the matrix cannot be all zero.**

We have $A=A^t$ and $\rho(A)=\rho(A^t)$ where $\rho(A)$ is the rank of A. But how to get the required result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that all diangonal elements are zero and $a_{ij}\neq 0$. Show that the $i$'th and the $j$'th column are linearly independent.

Comment: How to show that the i'th and the j'th column are linearly independent.

Comment: Take a linear combination of the two columns and look at the $i$'th and $j$'th row of that linear combination. What do you see?

Comment: @user1942348 Remember that in *any* linear space, two (this is important: **two**) vectors are *linearly dependent* iff one of the vectors is a scalar multiple of the other one. With this, this nice answer solves it all. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand the statement. But how to use that to prove the required result?

Comment: @user1942348  What is you definition of being linear dependent (or independent)? If given two specific vectors in say ${\Bbb R}^3$ do you know how to see if they are independent?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh For two vectors $u$ and $v$ being independent, one can write $cu+dv=0 \implies c=0=d$

Comment: Correct so using the hypothesis in my hint let $u$ and $v$ be the $i$'th and $j$'th column of $A$ and suppose that $cu+dv=0$. Look carefully at the $i$'th and $j$'th row of the vector $cu+dv$ and conclude....

Comment: @H.H.Rugh  "Look carefully..." please help me to see what you exactly want to mention'

Comment: Ok,... here we go: The i'th component: $(c u+d v)_i= c\times 0 - d \times (a_{ij})=0$ implies $d=0$ and $(cu + dv)_j= c \times a_{ij} + d\times 0=0$ implies $c=0$.